# Paginate results in Django using a paginated API?

Tags: django

I am using the search functionality of the OMDB API.

For each search, at most 10 results are returned at a time with an optional page parameter.

I have a Django search form to get the search results from the OMDB API. What would be the best way to paginate results from the API? I would like to have a button that when pressed will essentially append `&page=` to the current URL and submit the form again. Is there a Django-y way of accomplishing this?

I thought of using another form to pass in the page as a parameter but using multiple forms for a single search seems excessive. I also thought of using another field in the search form, `page`, to request the next page but I'm not sure how to use this as a button.

Comment: Are you doing this on the frontend? If so, then this is more of a javascript issue than a Django issue.

Comment: Yeah I'm doing it on the front end but I didn't know if it was possible to use Django's built-in Paginator or something else to achieve the same thing.

Comment: You'd need to include more of your code for better help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish it using `request.GET.urlencode` as seen below

```
<a href="{% url 'search_movie' %}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}&page={{ page|add:'-1'}}""> <- </a>

<a href="{% url 'search_movie' %}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}&page={{ page|add:'1'}}""> -> </a>
```

This way works but it doesn't seem very Django-y. Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish this.